# Make WPF control disappear when lost focus

Tags: wpf

I have a StackPanel that is being used as a container for other menuing controls.  I want the StackPanel to disappear when somewhere else on the UI is clicked (similar to typical menus/context menus).  I'm struggling with how to do this.  Any suggestions?  I've tried event triggers in the style like below but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostMouseCapture" >
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the stackPanel's trigger like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

and add this tag to Window (as well as other controls you want to when clicked, hide the stack panel):

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="disappearingStackPanel"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

You can also set `IsHitTestVisible=False` on controls that don't have mouse interaction so you don't have to add the trigger to them.

Comment: that didn't seem to work.  The XAML markup intellisense seemed to indicate that MouseDown wasn't a valid event

Comment: That's weird because MouseDown is one of UIElement's events.

Comment: did you run it? sometimes intellisense shows irrelevant errors.